# jQuery: Get content of clicked span by class

Tags: jquery

I've got several `span` tags, with the same class. Every `span` has it's unique id. Now I'd like to get the content and the id of the clicked `span` class.

I found out how I go about the id of the class, but I can't seem to get the content between the `<span></span>` tags. I tried `this.html()`, `this.html`, `this.text` and `this.tex()` but I can't get the text.

```
$(".row").click(function() {
    alert(this.id);
    alert(this.html);
}
```

HTML :

```
<div>
    <span class="row" id="1">Username of user 1</span>
    <span class="row" id="2">Username of user 2</span>
<div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `innnerHTML`, and you missed `);` at last.

```
$(".row").click(function() {
    alert(this.id);
    alert(this.innerHTML);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that solution looks the best to me (altough the other's work very well too ;))

Comment: it's the javascript-only solution. you tried with jquery and just missed the `$(this)` instead of your `this`

Answer (score 4):

Your `id`'s are invalid (they cannot start with a digit), so change them and try this

```
<div id="parent">
    <span class="row" id="s1">Username of user 1</span>
    <span class="row" id="s2">Username of user 2</span>
    ...
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#parent").on('click', '.row', function() {
    alert(this.id);
    alert(this.innerHTML);
});
```

doing so you will use `event delegation`, capturing the click event on the parent and defining the handler just once (and not, expensively, for every `span`)

Comment: Well, that id was just an example (but it did actually work). But thanks for the info.

Comment: nice solution just in need of `)`

Comment: @Raminson, my keyboard often does a lot of error and it misses chars. I need to change it :)

Answer (score 3):

Make use of [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function you will get content of element

```
$(".row").click(function() {
    alert(this.id);
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

#### Working Demo

Comment: Can't accept yet, but I like the innerHTML answer the best (looks prettier to me).

Comment: @Ahatius - no issues buddy....you should accept best answer tha meet you need........:) but if you are using jQuery than its better to go for .html() function which avaialble in libarary ....

Answer (score 2):

see here. http://jsfiddle.net/2aA92/1/

```
$(".row").click(function() {
  alert(this.id);
  alert($(this).text());
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
id = $(this).attr('id');
html = $(this).html();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".row").click(function() {
    alert(this.id);
    alert($(this).text()); // or this.innerHTML
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this instead:

```
$(".row").click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    alert($(this).html());
}

<div>
    <span class="row" id="1">Username of user 1</span
    <span class="row" id="2">Username of user 2</span
<div>
```

Comment: I know. I have been working on one of my jQuery plugins a lot lately and so I am used to having $(this) as a variable at hand (usually _this) so I messed up in my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  $(".row").click(function() {
    alert(this.id);
    alert($(this).html());
  });
}
```